Second filebeat instance on wazuh machine (UPDATE)
UPDATE
After some changes the first filebeat is working fine and sending logs from the /var/ossec/logs/alerts/alerts.json file to the wazuh dashboard. About the second filebeat the service is running "fine" but if I take a look to the logs i see these WARN and ERROR:
2024-05-22T21:47:01.369+0200   INFO     [registrar]     registrar/registrar.go:109      States Loaded from registrar: 0
2024-05-22T21:47:01.369+0200   INFO     [crawler]       beater/crawler.go:71    Loading Inputs: 1
2024-05-22T21:47:01.369+0200   WARN     [input] v2/loader.go:102        EXPERIMENTAL: The filestream input is experimental      {"input": "filestream", "stability": "Experimental", "deprecated": false}
2024-05-22T21:47:01.369+0200   INFO     [crawler]       beater/crawler.go:141   Starting input (ID: 16057552228904087780)
2024-05-22T21:47:01.369+0200   INFO     [crawler]       beater/crawler.go:108   Loading and starting Inputs completed. Enabled inputs: 1
2024-05-22T21:47:01.369+0200   INFO     [input.filestream]      compat/compat.go:110    Input filestream starting
2024-05-22T21:47:01.369+0200   ERROR    [input.filestream]      filestream/prospector.go:158    Failed to read regisry state for 'filestream::native::2773987-2056', cursor state will be ignored. Error was: unsupported   {"prospector": "file_prospector"}
2024-05-22T21:47:01.369+0200   ERROR    [input.filestream]      filestream/prospector.go:158    Failed to read regisry state for 'filestream::native::2774004-2056', cursor state will be ignored. Error was: unsupported   {"prospector": "file_prospector"}
I've been searching for a while but I've found nothing
Hi im trying to create a second filebeat instance on a Wazuh machine (all-in-one). The first one is deployed just how Wazuh creates it:
output.elasticsearch.hosts:
protocol: https  username: ${username}
password: ${password}
ssl.certificate_authorities: /etc/filebeat/certs/root-ca.pem
ssl.certificate: "/etc/filebeat/certs/wazuh-server.pem"
ssl.key: "/etc/filebeat/certs/wazuh-server-key.pem"
setup.template.json.enabled: true
setup.template.json.path: '/etc/filebeat/wazuh-template.json'
setup.template.json.name: 'wazuh'
setup.ilm.overwrite: true
setup.ilm.enabled: false filebeat.modules:
module: wazuh
alerts:
enabled: true
archives:
enabled: false
192.168.10.12:9200
logging.level: info
logging.to_files: true
logging.files:
path: /var/log/filebeat
name:filebeat
keepfiles: 7
permissions: 0644
logging.metrics.enabled: false
seccomp:
default_action: allow
syscalls:

action: allow

names:

rseq

I've created the second instance to send the same file /var/ossec/log/alerts/alerts.json to another machine with this configuration:
filebeat.inputs:
type: filestream
id: wazuh-clientCK
paths:
/var/ossec/logs/alerts/alerts.json
ignore_older: 24h
processors:
drop_event:
when:
regexp:
message: "windows_eventchannel"
output.logstash:
hosts: ["192.16.80.100:60022"]
I dont know if what im doing its possible or it would crush both services. Firstly, it looked like the second filebeat wasnt sending anything, after some changes, the first one crushed because the filed was already opened and the second filebeat, sent logs for a while and the stopped.
1º Filebeat (wazuh) :
enter image description here
2º Filebeat:
enter image description here
